# Switching page content in iphone UIWebview html5

Tags: jquery, iphone, html

I'm building an iphone app.  I have multiple "pages/sections" of content, and I'd like to see what you all thought was the best way to swap the content out.  I'm using jquery.  This doesn't look like a typical iphone app, and so I'm not using jqtouch.

Currently, I have a container div and I use the jquery load method to load in the different bits of content from separate html pages. This it works fine in theory but it's not "snappy" enough.

I tried to put all of the content on the main page in a hidden div and then use clone().appendTo... method but this was even slower (makes sense that it was slow in hind sight).  I'm wondering if anyone could recommend a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

The slowness was caused by the way I was animating the page not the content loading.